# Convert column into rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have table structure as below, Need the output as mentioned below

Table :

```
A                   B
CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID    4
CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID    3
CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID    2
CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID    1
CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID    0
```

Answer :

```
'4','3','2','1','0'
```

How to do it?

Comment: what oracle version do you use?

Comment: 11g, but These values are dynamic...

Answer (score 2):

As described, this isn't a pivot but aggregate string concatenation.  The Oracle function is `LISTAGG()`:

```
select listagg(b, ',') within group (order by b desc) as b
from t
group by a;
```

EDIT:

If you want single quotes around the values:

```
select listagg('''' || b || '''', ',') within group (order by b desc) as b
from t
group by a;
```

Comment: But this will return only one column, I'm not sure thats what the OP meant

Comment: @sagi By the way the answer is equal to the author's one

Comment: I agree, answer is correct @agent5566, but what is I need answer as '4','3','2','1','0' ...?

Comment: @rohansr002 just modify the query `...''''||listagg(b, ''',''')||'''' ...`

Comment: Hey @agent5566, thanks It works, I have changed internal value i.e. value from table in inner query.